# Sitecore CM StateServer Session Management

Tags: sitecore

Can I configure a multi clustered sitecore content management server with stateserver session mode ? I am using sitecore 8.1 .I tried with one server instance and it worked for me but not sure about multi clustered environment with load balanced .

Comment: I believe you will need to use MongoDB database as session database, following url will provide more information:
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/server_clusters_and_transferring_contact_sessions

Answer (score 1):

You can configure session server with clusters of content delivery or processing servers. 
There can be multiple scenario you can configure with.

Single standalone server

Single content delivery server and a separate content management server

Content delivery cluster with a sticky load balancer

Content delivery cluster with a non-sticky load balancer

For more information, you can review https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/session_state/session_state_configuration_scenarios

Comment: As per sitecore documentation,We should only use inproc as out proc is not supported by xDB for CM servers.